# Google Sheets - Script to “Replace” instead of “Create”, when file name is the same

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

EDIT to try and make this easier to understand:

Here is what I did:

I created a Google Spreadsheet. I created a SCRIPT that saves it to a Google Drive Folder using a File Name based on the date of service and Customer Name.

This is the Script I currently have:

```
// This creates a custom Menu Function so that I can save the file. 

function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Choice Menu')
  .addItem('Submit Form','saveAsSpreadsheet')
       .addToUi();  }      

// Saves Spreadsheet in Google Drive Folder

function saveAsSpreadsheet() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("0B8xnkPYxGFbUMktOWm14TVA3Yjg");
  DriveApp.getFileById(sheet.getId()).makeCopy(getFilename(), destFolder);
   } 

//This Function uses a cell "G4" (Which is Date and Customer Name) to create a file name. This file name will be then used for the above Script.

function getFilename() {

    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

    var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Manifest');
       var cell = sheet.getRange('G4');
    var filename = cell.getValue();

    return filename;}
```

So My code works GREAT except for one Problem.

Here is my Problem:

When I Save the Spreadsheet a 2nd time using the above Script, it saves a new file. I want to save it as a new file unless the Filename is the same. IF the file name is the same, I want to delete the original file, and then save the new file.

What I tried:
From what I understand reading the comments below, I need to run a code that "1. will need to run a query to see if any files exist with your chosen name, and then act accordingly. 2. If there are no files with that name, then go ahead and create one (using the function I listed above). If there is a file with the same name, 3. delete the original file and create a new one with the same name.

I tried for several days coming trying different options, and none of it worked, so I am looking to start over.

Appreciate any coding solutions or direction on where to go!

Comment: Can I ask you about ``it replace (not create a copy)``? If there is a file with the duplicated filename in the folder, how do you want to do? 1. You want to delete the existing file and create new file with the same filename. In this case, the file ID is different from the original file. 2. You want to replace the file without changing the file ID. In the current stage, this cannot be achieved yet.

Comment: If the spreadsheet is simple enough, you *could* copy the sheets from the new file to the old file and delete the old sheets. This will not work if you refer to named ranges on other sheets or if you have formulas that refer to other sheets or anything more complex (at least not without significant coding).

Comment: @s1c0j1 , it looks like my sheet is to complex for that. The file consists of multiple sheets.

Comment: @Tanaike , I would like to do your option 1. I do not care that the fileID is different.

Comment: @Ben Thank you for replying. I noticed that an answer was posted. I think that it will resolve your issue.

Comment: I am struggling coming up with the code. I added the new code in the original post under the "EDIT". I think I am on the wrong track. Do I need an If, Else, Then statement?

Comment: @Ben I noticed your comment just now. Can I ask you about your added script? What is ``data`` of ```folder.createFile(getFilename(), data)``? I had thought that at first, you wanted to copy the existing Spreadsheet and delete the original Spreadsheet. Can I ask you about what you want to do again?

Comment: @Tanaike I think my "data" is in error.. You are correct that I want to save a document. Here is what I want to do: If the File Name is not in the FolderID, I want it to CREATE a new spreadsheet. IF the File Name is in the Folder, I want to REPLACE (or delete the original) spreadsheet. MY top Code just creates a new file. My bottom Code was my attempt to use FilesByName() to search for the files, CreateFile(), to make a copy, and then use RemoveFile(). I think I am on the wrong track :(

Comment: @Ben Thank you for replying. I cannot understand about ``I want to save a document.``. I cannot understand about the original file for replacing. About ``I want it to CREATE a new spreadsheet.``, do you want to create new Spreadsheet which has no values in all cells? About ``I want to REPLACE (or delete the original) spreadsheet.``, do you want to replace the searched file with what? I apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: @Tanaike Im sorry that I was confusing. I rewrote my original post. Can you read it again and see if it makes sense? I just want a script that will save a spreadsheet to a google drive folder. If there already is a name in that folder, I want the script to delete the old file.

Comment: @Ben Before modified the script, can I confirm whether my understanding is correct? I understood your situation as follows. 1. When the Spreadsheet with the searched filename is existing in a specific folder, you want to replace it to the active Spreadsheet. 2. When the searched file is not existing in a specific folder, you want to copy the active Spreadsheet to the folder. If my understanding was not correct, please tell me.

Comment: @Tanaike Yes, That is what I am looking for! :)

Comment: @Ben Thank you for replying. I posted an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your situation, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

Comment: @Tanaike I appreciate it very much!!!! This works perfect for what I want to do! I would like to directly delete the file instead of putting it in the trash. Is that easy to do? I appreciate it! You are a lifesaver!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Your script is the container-bound script of Spreadsheet.
- When the Spreadsheet with the searched filename is existing in a specific folder, you want to replace it to the active Spreadsheet.

  - In the current stage, a file cannot be replaced while the file ID is not changed. So in this modified script, the active Spreadsheet is copied and the searched file is deleted.
- When the searched file is not existing in a specific folder, you want to copy the active Spreadsheet to the folder.
- You want to use the value returned from `getFilename()` as the filename.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? I think that there are several solutions for your situation. So please think of this as just one of them.

#### Modified script:

Please modify `saveAsSpreadsheet()` as follows.

```
function saveAsSpreadsheet() {
  var folderId = "0B8xnkPYxGFbUMktOWm14TVA3Yjg";
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  var files = folder.getFilesByName(getFilename());
  if (files.hasNext()) {
    files.next().setTrashed(true);
  }
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  DriveApp.getFileById(sheet.getId()).makeCopy(getFilename(), folder);
}
```

#### Note:

- In order to search the file, I used `getFilesByName()` because I thought the filename seems constant.
- `setTrashed()` for removing the file is used for this script. In this case, the file is put in the trash box. If you want to directly delete the file, you can achieve it using [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/delete). At that time, please tell me.

#### References:

- [getFilesByName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfilesbynamename)
- [setTrashed()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#setTrashed(Boolean))

### Edit:

If you want to directly delete the file, please modify the script as follows.

#### From:

```
files.next().setTrashed(true);
```

#### To:

```
var params = {method: "delete", headers: {Authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};
UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + files.next().getId(), params);
```

- I used the method using UrlFetchApp because I thought that in your situation, Drive API has already been enabled. In this case, you can use the delete method of Drive API by only replacing the script.

#### Reference:

- [delete method of Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/delete)

Comment: @Ben Thank you for replying. I added the method for directly deleting the file. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a step back and change your thinking about filenames.

In GDrive, files are identified by their unique ID. The `name` is just a metadata property alongside timeModified, owner, mimeType, etc. So having multiple files with the same name is as natural as having multiple files with the same mimeType.

Your code will need to run a query to see if any files exist with your chosen name, and then act accordingly. If there are no files with that name, then go ahead and create one. If there are, then you have the choice to update the existing file, or delete the original file(s) and create a new one with the same name.

Comment: This is on the right track! I'll try to see if I can figure out how to run querys and delete files.  It may be more complex than my coding abilities.

Comment: All the DriveApp methods are here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app. You want `searchFiles` and `removeFile`

Comment: Or getFilesByName() instead of searchFiles(). Might be a little easier if all you care about is the name.